# Cosine Similarity Matrix Loss Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, tensorflow

I am currently implementing this paper on generalised end to end loss: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10467.pdf

A batch of N speakers and M utterances are fed to the model which outputs an embedding vector of size P for each utterance.

The first step for calculating loss is constructing a cosine similarity matrix between each embedding vector and each centroid (for all speakers). [5]

Additionally when calculating the centroid for a true speaker (embedding speaker == centroid speaker), the embedding itself is removed from the centroid calculation to prevent trivial solutions. [8]

I have attempted to do this using matrices to maximise model training performance, however it's my first time working solely with linear algebra and would really appreciate if somebody could verify that my solution is correct given the requirements above.

The code runs and produces a value, I would like to make sure this value is correct.

```
@tf.function
def optim_similarity(embedded,w,b, N=64, M=10, P=256):

    # Create a view of the batch with an dimension for each "class" (speaker)
    embedded_split = tf.reshape(embedded,(N,M,P))

    # Calculate false speaker centroids 
    centers = tf.reduce_mean(embedded_split,axis=1) 
    
    # Calculate true speaker centroids 
    center_except = (tf.reduce_sum(tf.repeat(embedded_split,M,0),axis=1) - embedded) / M-1

    # Consruct equal shape matrices for centroids and embedding vectors
    center_matrix = tf.reshape(tf.repeat(centers,N*M),(N,N*M,P))    
    embedded_matrix = tf.broadcast_to(embedded,(N,N*M,P))

    # Create a boolean mask for true speaker centroids
    mask = tf.cast(tf.reshape(tf.repeat(tf.eye(N),P*M),(N,N*M,P)),bool)

    # Construct correct center matrix
    center_matrix = tf.where(mask,center_except,center_matrix)
    
    # Calculate loss and scale by weights and bias
    return w*tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(center_matrix,embedded_matrix) + b
```

Comment: Have you considered how to test it?

Comment: I don't have a working example to compare the results with. Unless I attempt it with dummy data manually for a small sample size, which might be the best option.